# plot a fuction in the same graph with different arguments next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, physics, axes

I have a matrix H, that can take 3 directional arguments. I want to plot the eigenvalues (just think of it as function) with one set of arguments & next to it - still in the same graph - the function with another set of arguments.
This is used in physics very often i.e. when plotting band structures.
It looks like:

[image]

This is not just changing 0 to Gamma and 2pi (lattice constant =1) to X, but really doing mutlipleplots next to each other in one plot.

Edit:

I have no measured data--> this is all calculated. I have a np.matrix (Hamiltonian - 8x8) that depends on 7 arguments, the only ones I change here are that of the directions.
g=Gamma, X, ... are positions (I know the directions of them.) 
Each plot is generated like this:

```
fig4=plt.figure()
LG=fig4.add_subplot(111)
for val in np.linspace(-np.pi/a, 0, 1000):
   LG.scatter([val]*8, H(val, val , val, -15.2, -s*10.25, 19.60, -5.30))
plt.grid()
plt.title(r"$L-\Gamma$")
plt.xlabel(r"$k$ in high symmetry points")
plt.xticks([-C*0.5, 0.], ["L", "$\Gamma$"])
plt.ylabel("energy/eV")
plt.show()
```

I included the physics, so that physicians understand it easier. In case they are not many here:

I have a function plot1 and plot2 & I want to append plot2 horizontally in one graph with same y-axes but different x- axes. Like in the picture(from g-X is one function, from X to W another and so on).

Edit2: The answer of TobyD & pathoren made it possible to plot a function w/ several arguments next to each w/ free arguments.
I think that my problem is in principle solveable by this, but since I don't have functions but a matrix and want to calculate eigenvalues and have more than one directional argument it's complicated. I manage to produce a plot I only want to cut horizontally together (but not like paint, but with one x-axes description).

Edit3: Thank you pathoren  & TobyD for your help. The easiest way was just to change the argument x+something, x-something, now I have more than way, which can  proof usefull eventually.

[final answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqMN9.png)

Comment: Please add what you have done so far and some sample data. It sounds to me like you should just plot everything on one axis and add a dotted `axhspan` line at zero.

Comment: Go to [the gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#) and look around til you see a picture that looks close to what you want to do then look at its code to see how they did it. Like [plot_fivethirtyeight](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#style_sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I'm understanding what you're after correctly.

Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,n, width_ratios = [width_1,...,width_n])
axes = [plt.subplot(subplot) for subplot in gs]
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

Where n is the number of differing argument sets you want to be plotting and width_n is the width of each in whatever units you choose based on your normalisation.

The subplots_adjust sets the space between the subplots to 0. GridSpec gives you finer grained control over the sizes of each. The `sharey` flag doesnt work with gridspec so we have to fiddle with the y-ticks manually.

You can then plot the function for each argument set, in an element of axes, with whatever ranges you want. Basically treat each element of axes as one of the graphs which you wish to concatonate together.

Using the same example as @pathoren:

```
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios = [3, 2, 1])
axes = [plt.subplot(subplot) for subplot in gs]
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.linspace(2, 5 ,100)
z = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

f1 = f(x, 1, 2, 3)
f2 = f(y, 3, -2, 0)
f3 = f(z, -1, 2, 1)

axes[0].plot(x, f1, label='f1')
axes[0].set_xticks([0, 10])
axes[0].set_xticklabels(["L", "X"])
axes[0].yaxis.tick_left()    

axes[1].plot(y, f2, label='f2')
axes[1].set_xticks([5])
axes[1].set_xticklabels(["G"])
axes[1].yaxis.set_tick_params(size=0)
plt.setp(axes[1].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

axes[2].plot(z, f3, label='f3')
axes[2].set_xticks([2*np.pi])
axes[2].set_xticklabels(["Y"])
axes[2].yaxis.tick_right()    
axes[2].set_xlim([z[0],z[-1]])
plt.setp(axes[2].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

plt.show()
```

Note that the functions for changing subplot attributes like the xticks are slightly different. Using `axes[2].set_xlim` ensures the last graph cuts off nicely.

[image: Example Graph]

Comment: Yes, I meant it like that - the x-values can overlap. Additionally I would like to set the scope for each part on the x-axes on my own. i.e.: K=10 to L=20 is 5 units & from L=20 to M=50 is 3 units in the pathoren graph. (K, L, M are in reality coordinates of 3D-objects & the length should be determined be the norm of the connection vector, not the length in one direction)

Comment: @Carsten I've updated my anwser to allow for specification of the widths

Answer (score -1):

Below is a script where a function `f` takes 3 parameters `a, b, c`.  The x-values are split into three different regimes, `x1, x2, x3`, with corresponding function values `f1, f2, f3`.  At some breakpoints (defined by `x_ticks`) there are lines drawn, and the xticks are only shown for those points.  The xlabels are set by `x_ticklabels`, only at `x_ticks`-position.

```
    import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
f1 = f(x1, 1, 2, 3)
x2 = np.linspace(10, 20, 100)
f2 = f(x2, 3, -2, 0)
x3 = np.linspace(20, 50, 100)
f3 = f(x3, -1, 2, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(x1, f1, label='f1')
ax.plot(x2, f2, label='f2')
ax.plot(x3, f3, label='f3')
x_ticks = [10, 20, 50]
x_ticklabels = ['K', 'L', 'M']
ax.vlines(x_ticks, ax.get_ylim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[1])
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticklabels)
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And now I want these 3 functions in one graph but next to each other, where the y-axis stay the same, but the x-axis is freely chooseable.
Like f1(x, 1, 2, 3) with 0<x<10 | f2(x,3,-2,0) with 2<x<5 | f3(x, -1,2,1) with 0<x<2pi